# Why Linux used memory is growing?

Tags: linux, centos, ssh, scp, openssh

I use Rocky8.5 Linux and I am experiencing growing the size of used memory when I start transferring gigantic files by SCP!

Here is the scenario, I have an ESXi in datacenter A and a VM in datacenter B. In order to access ESXi I have to make IPSec tunnel. The tunnel is made and ready. I have a 350GB file that I want to copy to the remote VM. The only tool that I have is SCP at the moment. other tools like Rsync or FTP neither available nor fits the current topology.

When I start transferring data using SCP, used memory starts increasing:

```
[root@gateway]# free -h
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           15Gi       1.4Gi        11Gi        16Mi       2.5Gi        13Gi
Swap:         4.0Gi          0B       4.0Gi
```

At the same time buff/cache is getting increased which is normal I think. When I run `sync; echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches` buff/cache shrinks:

```
[root@gateway]# free -h
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           15Gi       1.4Gi        13Gi        16Mi       119Mi        13Gi
Swap:         4.0Gi          0B       4.0Gi
```

But the used memory remains at the same size. I am experiencing the VM crash after downloading 60~70GB of the file.

Does anyone have any suggestion?

**UPDATE #1**
I have a running copy, as you see the `buff/cache` value is **2.8Gi** and when I drop caches, it is returned to **free**, but the value of **used** was not changed:

```
[root@gateway]# free -h
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           15Gi       1.6Gi        11Gi        16Mi       2.8Gi        13Gi
Swap:         4.0Gi          0B       4.0Gi
[root@gateway]# sync; echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches 
[root@gateway]# free -h
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           15Gi       1.6Gi        13Gi        16Mi       127Mi        13Gi
Swap:         4.0Gi          0B       4.0Gi
[root@gateway]#
```

**UDATE #2**
It looks like this is a memory leakage of SSH, I switched to sftp to download the files, the result was the same.

Comment: Are those measurements from the source or the target of the copying. Those seem to be indicating that the file is being cached, which might be pointless, but won't hurt anything.

Comment: @Henriksupportsthecommunity, I am downloading from remote ESXi and SCP is executed on the Linux machine I am having problem with it

Comment: I didn't ask where you executed `scp`, but where you performed those *measurements*.

Comment: @Panki, I increased the memory from 4GB to 16GB for debugging. If I leave the machine downloading from remote the memory utilization will become 100% and the machine will become unresponsive

Comment: @Henriksupportsthecommunity, on the target machine

Comment: It's a problem that the VM crashes, if you use a sensible technology for making VM (you use ESXi on one end, you haven't said what you use in the end that gives problems) it shouldn't be related to the copying though. You can try to prefix `scp` with `nocache` (On Debian - and Ubuntu - it's in a pakage called nocache, I have no idea where to get it on anything else), that should cause it to stop caching it.

Comment: @Henriksupportsthecommunity, the VM on which I run SCP, is hosted on ESXi, scp connects to another ESXi machine directly to its SSH service to fetch the file. The ESXi machine which serves the file, doesn't show any problem. The Linux machine (VM) in the receiving side misbehaves. It allocates memory but doesn't release, I have no problem with cache since when I drop cache it flushes and `free` command shows that the buffer was fushed. My point is that `free` shows the "used" memory increasing but it is not obvious in `ps` command output that where the stolen memory has been used.

Comment: What directory are you copying the file to? Is it /tmp or something like that? Is it possible the file is being written to a virtual (memory-backed) filesystem?

Comment: @Kenster,  it's an XFS partition mounted to /mnt.